# My ntellij-idea-ultimate-edition always dump when I run a Java program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dump, arch

My IntelliJ-idea-ultimate-edition always dump when I run a Java program, it makes me confuse.

How can I fix it?

My os is Arch Linux, and the idea version is 2019.3.4-1.

Here is a dump output in the idea's console:

```
2020-04-02 16:29:53
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b08 mixed mode):

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c225800 nid=0x5894 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread2" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c21f000 nid=0x5893 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c21c800 nid=0x5892 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c21b000 nid=0x5891 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c219800 nid=0x5890 runnable [0x00007f7a0de7d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x000000076db6ea30> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    - locked <0x000000076db6ea30> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2$1.run(AppMainV2.java:64)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c17f000 nid=0x588f waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c14f000 nid=0x588e in Object.wait() [0x00007f7a0fefd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076da08ee8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x000000076da08ee8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c14a800 nid=0x588d in Object.wait() [0x00007f7a0fffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000076da06c08> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x000000076da06c08> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c00c000 nid=0x5887 runnable [0x00007f7a42513000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x000000076da1c438> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x000000076dc986e0> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:100)
    at java.util.Scanner.readInput(Scanner.java:804)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1483)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c140800 nid=0x588c runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c021000 nid=0x5888 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c023000 nid=0x5889 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c024800 nid=0x588a runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c026800 nid=0x588b runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7a3c228000 nid=0x5895 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 12

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 74240K, used 6436K [0x000000076da00000, 0x0000000772c80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 64000K, 10% used [0x000000076da00000,0x000000076e049130,0x0000000771880000)
  from space 10240K, 0% used [0x0000000772280000,0x0000000772280000,0x0000000772c80000)
  to   space 10240K, 0% used [0x0000000771880000,0x0000000771880000,0x0000000772280000)
 ParOldGen       total 169472K, used 0K [0x00000006c8e00000, 0x00000006d3380000, 0x000000076da00000)
  object space 169472K, 0% used [0x00000006c8e00000,0x00000006c8e00000,0x00000006d3380000)
 Metaspace       used 3828K, capacity 4610K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 417K, capacity 430K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
```

I think it isn't OutOfMemory or GC.

I don't want to see this in console.Could u help me to hidden it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution as per [this post on the IntelliJ community forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001812320-Thread-dump-on-every-launch):

**Help | Find Action** > search for 'Registry' > disable the `debugger.attach.to.process.action` registry key.